# CSS BaseLink and additionalLinks within a Div

Tags: css, styles

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="boxLayer">
<a href="a.html"></a>
<div class="text">Result</div>
<div class="additionalLink"><a href="b.html"></a></div>
</div>

.boxLayer{
position: relative;
float:left;
height:28px;
width:100%;
border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
background-color: #fff;
}

.boxLayer a {
display:block;
height:100%;
width: 100%;
background: white;
}

.boxLayer a:hover{
background-color: #ffeecc;
}
```

The idea is to have a box with a text shown at the left side of this box and an additional link at the right side of the box. When i hover over the box, the backgroundColor of the box is shown, also when i hover over the text or the second link. I have managed to create the Box, but when i add the text or the link, the hover-Effect of the box is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will be your answer

**please check the fiddle:**

```css
.boxLayer {
    position: relative;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.boxLayer:hover {
    background-color: #ffeecc;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxLayer">
    <a href="a.html" class="firstLink"></a>
    <div class="text">Result</div>
    <div class="additionalLink"><a href="b.html">&nbsp;</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the text and the link should appear within the box

Comment: tu, but it is not possible to call the link of the box